# Is that possible to enqueue a script src on function.php wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have JavaScript on my front-page-template like below, I want to remove it from the front-page-template and enqueue it on the function.php of wordpress theme, is that possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//shop.spreadshirt.com/shopfiles/shopclient/shopclient.nocache.js"></script>
```

Comment: just being included in the page is not really a problem if its not used

Comment: Yes this is possible. Go to this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script to know more.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Put this into your functions.php file.

```
<?php

function my_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'shop-js', '//shop.spreadshirt.com/shopfiles/shopclient/shopclient.nocache.js'
    );

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I had tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is correct, did you call the wp_head(); function in your header.php?